# Cheap client identification vs proper SSL client authentication

Tags: php, node.js, ssl, https

I'm having a PHP script connect to and communicate with a Node.js server. The Node.js should only respond to requests from the PHP script so I need to make sure the Node server has some sort of authentication method.

Now to identify it's actually the PHP script connecting, I was thinking of just using some cheap authentication like sending a pre-shared secret along with the request that the PHP script is making. The Node server simply compares this with it's own secret and if they match, it can be assumed it's the script connecting and not somebody else (assuming SSL has built-in ways to prevent replay attacks).

This whole process will be done over HTTPS which has the added bonus of the script being able to confirm the identity of the Node server.

Is this secure enough or should I do some proper SSL-based client authentication? After all, it's over HTTPS so the pre-shared secret shouldn't be easily sniffed out right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTPS is not replayable (because [the ServerHello message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake_in_detail) includes a random number used to produce the shared key for the connection), and since you are talking over a secure channel your pre-shared secret cannot be sniffed either. As a quick and not-so-dirty solution your scheme sounds fine to me.

Comment: I might use a request signing method instead of sending the actual secret, but that shouldn't make that much of a difference. Otherwise, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTPS connection (as always, if configured with suitable cipher suites, and if the client verifies the server certificate properly) will protect the communication, and will prevent replays of the HTTP request (since the actual HTTP request won't be visible and since another client wouldn't be able to replay the exact same content because it would have a different SSL session ID).

Having a pre-shared secret between your server and your PHP script sounds fine.

You could use client-certificate authentication, but it would make it more complicated, without necessary benefits in this case. You would have to generate your own cert and make the server trust it. More importantly, you may have to configure your Node.js server for re-negotiation (not sure if it's possible), otherwise, all the clients connecting to that HTTPS server would be prompted for a client-certificate, which is likely to be inconvenient for most users who don't need it.